# Connect computers from different networks

Tags: networking

Here is my situation:

There is normal network with a router at `192.168.0.1` that connects to internet. I would like to create another network (that doesn't need internet) with AP (currently TL-WA801N at `192.168.1.10`) that works as DHCP, connect it to a simple switch and connect another computers to it. I have one PC with two LAN cards that is connected to both networks. How computers from different networks could see/ping each other? I made simple schematic. How could PC2 see/ping PC3?

[image]

Comment: I think you will find if the computers can see each other and ping each other that they will likely have internet access too. Disconnect the network with no Internet desired from the main network entirely.

Comment: My mistake, it wasnt' clear from the question. Computers on different network (PC2 and PC3) can not see/ping each other. I would like to accomplish that.

Comment: If they cannot use the internet, I really believe the best way is just to disconnect that part of the network. They do not need services.

Comment: point is: i want that pc2 can see/ping pc3, pc3 doesn't need internet.

Comment: Networking to allow seeing / pinging also allows internet. So you would have to severely hamper PC 3 and that may screw things up.

Comment: Probably what you need to do is set up a secure network (secure Router). Hook everything up to it and then deny the MAC address of computers not needing internet at the router level. This will be better than hampering computers.

Comment: since PC2 and PC3 are in different subnet, router is needed if they want to communicate with each other

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is they cannot.
These two networks are separate beings, and PC1  works as "client" on both.

If you want to connect 2 or more networks together, basically you need a router.

In theory, You can try software resolution, but I don't recommend that.
In win 10 in network connection, you can try to create a bridge from both interfaces.

Look at this tutorial https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10  - this is a good start - but  bridging in windows can be painful and you may need to do some crazy stuff like modifying  routes in windows to do this all working in a way you need

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want to do, however not with your current wiring diagram. You want PC3 to talk to PC2 while not having access to the PC2 network (which includes greater internet access), which simply will not work as this is.

So, we need to clearly define your two networks and for each PC-to-PC connection you want to have, connect each PC to that network. Assuming I understand your requirements correctly, it should look like this:

[image: New Network Diagram]

Now, the first thing you might say is "Only my PC1 has two LAN/Ethernet ports, not PC2!". There are some solutions for this, but we do need to create some sort of logical-to-the-OS separation of LAN connections on PC2:

1. If your switch hardware supports VLANs, you could go that route while creating a secondary virtual Ethernet port on PC2 that uses that VLAN. This is the most complicated solution to setup, but requires no additional hardware if yours supports this feature.
2. Buy a $15 USB-to-Ethernet adapter for PC2. Simplest solution. I use the Plugable brand ones at work.